# How to string match using dplyr mutate in R using a vector of strings

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to string match values in a dataframe column with elements in a vector of strings. If there is a match I would like the element in the vector to be returned. I am using a function in `dplyr:mutate` to try and achieve this.

I have a dataframe called `keywords` like so:

```
+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+
|      Page.Title       | Event.Label | Unique.Events |
+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+
| Awesome Sale in Spain | pool        |           123 |
| Spain Holidays        | pool        |            34 |
| Edinburgh Castles     | sea-view    |            45 |
| London Houses         | help-to-buy |            56 |
| Cars in Greece        | beach       |            82 |
+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+
```

I have a vector called `locations` like so:

`c('Edinburgh', 'London', 'Spain')`

I created a function called `location_finder` like so:

```
function(locations,col_name){
  for (i in locations) {
    if (str_detect(col_name, i)) {
      return(i)
    } else {
      return ('Other')
    }
  }
}
```

My code is:

```
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)
require(stringr)

df_working <- rowwise(keywords) %>%
  mutate(Location=location_finder(locations,Page.Title))
```

My expected output is:

```
+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
|      Page.Title       | Event.Label | Unique Events | Location  |
+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
| Awesome Sale in Spain | pool        |           123 | Spain     |
| Spain Holidays        | pool        |            34 | Spain     |
| Edinburgh Castles     | sea-view    |            45 | Edinburgh |
| London Houses         | help-to-buy |            56 | London    |
| Cars in Greece        | beach       |            82 | Other     |
+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+
```

My results only match on 'Edinburgh' only, otherwise 'Other' is only returned. Presumably because 'Edinburgh' is the first element in the vector. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could rewrite your function using grepl, and then extract the match from your cities list as such:

```
string <- "Awesome Sale in Spain"
cities <- c('Edinburgh', 'London', 'Spain')
cities[sapply(cities, grepl, string)]
```

This solution would also return multiple cities if there are multiple matches.

EDIT:

Here it has been done for a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(Page.Title = c("Awesome Sale in Spain", "Spain Holidays", "Edinburgh Castles", "London Houses", "Cars in Greece"),
                 Event.Label = c("pool", "pool", "sea-view", "help-to-buy", "beach"))

cities <- c('Edinburgh', 'London', 'Spain')

df$cities <- sapply(df$Page.Title, function(title) {
  city <- cities[sapply(cities, grepl, title)]
})
```

EDIT2:

If you want to handle cases, then just use:

```
city <- cities[sapply(cities, grepl, title, ignore.case = TRUE)]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer which should be faster on bigger sets:

```
location_finder <- function(text, keywords, case_insensitive = FALSE, unique_pattern = TRUE) {
  lapply(text, function(t) {
    out <- stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(
      str = t,
      pattern = paste0("\\b",
                       keywords,
                       "\\b"), #Use word boundaries
      vectorize_all = TRUE,
      omit_no_match = FALSE,
      simplify = FALSE,
      opts_regex = stringi::stri_opts_regex(
        case_insensitive = case_insensitive
      )
    )
    out[is.na(out)] <- NULL
    if (unique_pattern) {
      return(unique(unlist(out)))
    } else {
      return(unlist(out))
    }
  })
}
```

You should be able to use it in your approach like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(stringi)
df <- data.frame(Page.Title = c("Awesome Sale in Spain", "Spain Holidays", "Edinburgh Castles", "London Houses", "Cars in Greece"),
                 Event.Label = c("pool", "pool", "sea-view", "help-to-buy", "beach"))
locations <- c('Edinburgh', 'London', 'Spain')

df_working <- df %>%
  mutate(Location = location_finder(text = Page.Title, keywords = locations))

# If you don't like the NULL in the new column
df_working$Location[sapply(df_working$Location, is.null)] <- "other"
```

There is a parallel version of this in [my own package](https://github.com/JBGruber/LexisNexisTools#lookup-keywords) if you are interested. Just grab the source code if you are not interested in the rest of the package.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do using `strsplit` and `which` function:

```
# split the input string
vals <- sapply(df$cities, function(x) strsplit(x, ' '), USE.NAMES = F)

# check which names are in vector
vals <- sapply(vals, function(x) x[which(x %in% myvec)])

# create new column and set missing value as 'Other'
df$new_col <- vals
df$new_col <- ifelse(is.na(df$new_col),'Other', df$new_col)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
library(stringr)

keywords$Location<-sapply(df$Page.Title,function(x) na.omit(str_extract(x,locations))[1])

keywords$Location[is.na(keywords$Location)]<-"Other"
```